# Save Embedded Object from OneNote

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-2007, onenote

My goal is to extract embedded documents from a OneNote notebook programmatically. The embedded documents are likely to be Office documents, PDFs, and other arbitrary files. I do not have any difficulty getting a Base64 string for inline images, but I do have a problem getting a Base64 string for other file types.

I am using VS 2008 C#, OneNote 2007, Windows XP SP3.

I am using a sample .ONE file, which consists of a small amount of text, a PDF file, and one inline image. I am able to identify the ID of the containing page and the ID of PDF. I have hard-coded the IDs into the following example.

```
        // ID of the Application
        string strID;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application onApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application();
        onApplication.OpenHierarchy(@"D:\Projects\OneNote\test.one",
            System.String.Empty, out strID, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.CreateFileType.cftSection);


        string strXML1;
        onApplication.GetPageContent("{460ABC12-855F-09E4-3724-85E8DE17BD57}{1}{B0}", out strXML1, PageInfo.piAll);

        // Get page reference
        string strXML2;
        onApplication.GetPageContent("{4AA5B6DF-1C90-0B3D-3FFD-687B0AF4A632}{1}{B0}", out strXML2, PageInfo.piAll);

        //Get Hyperlink to embedded object
        string strHyperlink;
        onApplication.GetHyperlinkToObject("{4AA5B6DF-1C90-0B3D-3FFD-687B0AF4A632}{1}{B0}", "{23A17F23-F743-0C9B-082A-BC6BD5D9CA6E}{13}{B0}", out strHyperlink);

        //Condition to ensure that the ObjectID is good.
        if ((strHyperlink != null) && (strHyperlink != ""))
        {
            //Get Base64 string.
            string strBase64;
            onApplication.GetBinaryPageContent("{4AA5B6DF-1C90-0B3D-3FFD-687B0AF4A632}{1}{B0}", "{23A17F23-F743-0C9B-082A-BC6BD5D9CA6E}{13}{B0}", out strBase64);
        }
```

The application returns a good hyperlink whether I reference the PDF or the inline image. The application returns a good Base64 string for the inline image. However, the application returns error `0x8004200f The binary object does not exist.` for the PDF. The same is true if I try a version containing an embedded Word document.

How can I get a Base64 string for the PDF?
I am open to using `http://onom.codeplex.com/`, but I have not found a solution there.

By the way, I am aware that IDs may not be the same from from one OneNote session to another. In my tests, I make sure the IDs are correct manually viewing the XML in debug mode.

Here is a snippet of the XML written to strXML2.

`The inline image`

```
<![CDATA[Attachment_Test_01]]>
</one:T>
</one:OE>
</one:Title>
<one:Image format=\"jpg\" originalPageNumber=\"0\" lastModifiedTime=\"2013-06-10T18:39:46.000Z\" objectID=\"{1A32E30F-091E-4F03-8147-D00D0D16C6FD}{20}{B0}\">
<one:Position x=\"90.0\" y=\"104.400001525879\" z=\"3\"/>
<one:Size width=\"767.9999389648437\" height=\"576.0\"/>
<one:Data>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJ (SNIP)
```

`The embedded PDF`

```
<![CDATA[4\r\n‘4]]>
</one:OCRText>
<one:OCRToken startPos=\"0\" region=\"0\" line=\"0\" x=\"564.631591796875\" y=\"250.1052703857422\" width=\"6.063148498535156\" height=\"5.30526351928711\"/>
<one:OCRToken startPos=\"3\" region=\"1\" line=\"1\" x=\"684.3789672851562\" y=\"462.3157653808594\" width=\"5.305229187011718\" height=\"6.821067810058594\"/>
</one:OCRData>
</one:Image>
<one:InsertedFile pathCache=\"C:\\TEST\\D62228.pdf\" pathSource=\"C:\\C++_Neural_Networks_And_Fuzzy_Logic.pdf\" preferredName=\"C++_Neural_Networks_And_Fuzzy_Logic.pdf\" lastModifiedTime=\"2013-06-10T18:39:43.000Z\" objectID=\"{23A17F23-F743-0C9B-082A-BC6BD5D9CA6E}{13}{B0}\">
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetBinaryPageContent` API can be used only to retrieve image and ink data. For embedded files the `pathCache` attribute points to the file stored in OneNote cache folder. You can simply read that file.